# Implementing an SQL wrapper with entity mapping

Tags: c#, sql-server

I was trying to implement a wrapper in C# for SQL Server.

The normal workflow without wrapper is fetching the data into a `datatable` using `direct SQL query` and then mapping the columns by names into entities.

But as a wrapper is better to accept a `mapping function` which describes which column maps to which fields of an enumerable.

So, something like this :

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
enumerableList = dbManager.Execute("** sql query **", /* some method to specify mapping */);
```

The enumerable will then contain the result from the `database`, mapped by the execute method. But I am unsure how to specify the mapping?

Even if I do then how to deal with the different data types for each column in the mapping?

Comment: Use AutoMapper for map data http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html

Comment: Why not using a micro ORM like Dapper? https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing such a wrapper from bare bones is not that easy. But it is possible. There is an ADO wrapper library in Github : [ADOWrapper](https://github.com/jakobyc/AdoWrapper)

The implementation is pretty straightforward.

**Short Answer**

1. How to specify mapping between columns? - Use `Func`
2. How to deal with the different data types? You can **write an extension**

**Long Answer**

Make a generic method that takes as input the query and a `Func` Delegate (and optional third parameter to pass query parameters as dictionary)

```
    public ICollection<T> Execute<T>(string query, Func<IDataReader, T> map, IDictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
    {
        ICollection<T> collection = new List<T>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = CreateCommand(connection, query, parameters))
            {
                using (IDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        collection.Add(map.Invoke(reader));
                    }
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }

        return collection;
    }
```

Implementation of AddParameter AND CreateCommand:

```
        private void AddParameter(IDbCommand command, string parameter, object value)
        {
            IDbDataParameter param = command.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = parameter;
            param.Value = value;

            command.Parameters.Add(param);
        }

        private SqlCommand CreateCommand(SqlConnection connection, string query, 
            IDictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
        {
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = query;

            if(parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in parameters)
                {
                    AddParameter(command, parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                }
            }

            return command;
        }
```

You can call the method like this :

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
var enumerableList = manager.Execute("** query **",
    (reader) =>
    {
        return new UserInfo()
        {
            FirstName = reader.Get<string>("FirstName"),
            LastName = reader.Get<string>("LastName "),
        };
    })
```

The Get method makes it easy to manage different data types being fetched from column. But it is not an inbuilt method. So you need to write an extension for Data Reader:

```
public static class DataReaderExtension
    {
        public static T Get<T>(this IDataReader reader, string column) where T : IComparable
        {
            try
            {
                int index = reader.GetOrdinal(column);

                if (!reader.IsDBNull(index))
                {
                    return (T)reader[index];
                }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { throw new Exception($"Column, '{column}' not found."); }

            return default(T);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> GetColumns(this IDataReader reader)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> columns = new List<string>();
            if (reader != null && reader.FieldCount > 0)
            {
                columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                                    .Select(index => reader.GetName(index))
                                    .ToList();
            }

            return columns;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correct understand, you want something like this:

```
public static List<T> ReadRows<T>(this SqlHelper sql, string query, SqlParameter[] 
parameters, Func<SqlDataReader, T> projection)
{
        var command = GetSqlCommand(query, CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters);
        return sql.ExecuteReader(command, reader => reader.Select(projection).ToList());
}
```

And use like:

```
var members = _unitOfWork.SqlHelper.ReadRows("spGetMembersByUserCompanies", parameters, _memberProjection);

readonly Func<SqlDataReader, MemberVm> _memberProjection = (r) => new MemberVm
    {
        InvitationId = r.Get<int?>("InvitationId"),
        UserName = r.Get<string>("UserName"),
        RoleName = r.Get<string>("RoleName"),
        InvitationStatus = (InvitationStatus)r.Get<int>("InvitationStatus"),
        LogoUrl = r.Get<string>("LogoUrl")
    };
```

It is a piece of my code. I hope it is start to resolve your problem.